# Asmx Web Service to Download Large File

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, large-files

I have a problem when downloading a large file (around 400mb) with a web service.
Today we have an asmx web service (using soap protocol) to get this file (returning a byte []) and a windows service using a reference of this web service to download the files. If the file has a large size, it consumes a lot of RAM MEMORY (almost all of the available computer memory).
I wanna know what is a better way to download a file by windows service, without consuming a lot of ram memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your files are, you may get very good results with built-in compression to reduce the file size and, subsequently, your issue. Check the `EnableDecompression` property of the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` class, which you can subclass on your client and use the compression functionality offered by IIS. This approach could eliminate the need for any other modification. A few hundred megabytes should not be such a big deal, or does your app consume more?

Edit: Upon reading your question more carefully, it occurs to me that you are looking for a different way to dl your files altogether. In that case, it would probably be the simplest approach to just expose the file via http/ftp and make your windows service download it with the `WebClient` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MTOM](http://www.tfabraham.com/blog/2006/12/optimize-large-data-transfer-in-web-services-with-mtom/) for large file transformation.

Comment: So what that does is decode the base64 payload into binary? I wonder which of those two formats compresses better.